# runtime error (SIGABRT) - SPOJ

Tags: c++, factorial

My code runs fine in code blocks but, when I submit it shows `runtime sigabrt` error, what does this error mean?

When I initialize the size of pointer array as 200 it works fine but I want to know what is this error?

link for question is: http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL2/

Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>


    using namespace std;
    void multiply(int x,int *nums,int &len){
        int carry=0;
        int prod;
        for (int j=0;j<len;j++){
            prod=nums[j]*x+carry;
            carry=prod/10;
            nums[j]=prod%10;
        }
        while (carry){
            nums[len]=carry%10;
            carry=carry/10;
            len++;
        }

   }


   int main()
   {
   int t,n;

   cin>>t;
   int arr[100];
   for (int i=0;i<t;i++){
         cin>>arr[i];
   }
   for (int i=0;i<t;i++){
         n=arr[i];
         if (n==0){cout<<0<<endl;}
         else{
        int *nums= new int[0];
        nums[0]=1;
    int len=1;
    for (int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        multiply(i,nums,len);

    }


    for (int i=len-1;i>=0;i--){

        cout<<nums[i];

    }
    cout<<endl;}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int *nums= new int[0]; nums[0]=1;` -- Either you didn't see this obvious error, or you're just writing code and not learning the language, just to submit it to SPOJ.

Comment: No sir i'm asking what type of error is this sigabrt ... And how it is related to nums[0]

Comment: You are creating a 0-element buffer, thus accessing any element in `nums`, including element 0, is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Change `int *nums = new int[0];` to `int *nums = new int[x]`, where `x` is the maximum size of the array (depending on the number of digits you're expecting in the factorial). According to the constraints (`1 <= n <= 100`) A suitable value of `x` [would be](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1075430/266439) `158`.

`int *nums = new int[n]` allocates memory for an `n` element array.